# Triying to evaluate $\oint_{C}\frac{z^{m}}{1-z^{n}}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm triying to evaluate $\oint_{C}\frac{z^{m}}{1-z^{n}}dz$ being $C$ a unitary circle bordering the roots of the denominator.

I transform the integral into another using the fact that $|z|\leq 1$ to expand $\frac{z^{m}}{1-z^{n}}$

$\oint_{C}z^{m} dz + \oint_{C}z^{m+n} dz + \oint_{C}z^{m+2n} dz + \cdots =$

$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \oint_{C}z^{m + k n}dz$

and next I use $z = e^{2 \pi i \tau}$

$2\pi i  \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}  \oint_{\gamma} e^{2\pi i \tau (m + k n)}  e^{2\pi i\tau} d\tau =$

$2\pi i  \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}  \oint_{\gamma} e^{2\pi i \tau (m + k n + 1)} d\tau \\$

Whit $\gamma$ now equals to:

$\gamma = \gamma_{0,0}(t) \bigcup   \gamma_{0,1}(\theta) \bigcup_ {k = 0}^{n-1} \gamma_{1,k}(t) \bigcup_ {k = 1}^{n-1} \gamma_{2,k}(\theta) \bigcup \gamma_{3,1}(\theta) \bigcup \gamma_{3,0}(t)$

being the paths:

\begin{cases}
        \gamma_{0,0}(t) =-t(1-\varepsilon) i+ i &  t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus t  \in \left[ 0 , 1 \right] \\
        \gamma_{0,1}(\theta) =\varepsilon e^{- i \theta} &  \theta \in \mathbb{R}\setminus  \theta  \in \left[ \frac{3\pi}{2} , 2 \pi \right]\\
        \gamma_{1,k}(t) = \frac{1}{n} \left( t  - \varepsilon n (2 t - 1) + k \right) &  t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus t  \in \left[ 0 , 1 \right] \wedge  k \in \mathbb{N} \setminus k \in \left[ 0 , n-1 \right]  \\
  \gamma_{2,k}(\theta) = \varepsilon e^{- i \theta} + \frac{k}{n} &  \theta \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \theta  \in \left[ \pi , 2 \pi \right] \wedge  k \in \mathbb{N} \setminus k \in \left[ 1 , n-1 \right]  \\
        \gamma_{3,1}(\theta) =\varepsilon e^{- i \theta} + 1 & \theta \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \theta  \in \left[ \pi, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]\\
       \gamma_{3,0}(t) =  t(1 - \varepsilon)i + \varepsilon i + 1 &  t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus t  \in \left[ 0 , 1 \right] \\
    \end{cases}

with $\varepsilon$ a cuantity as small as one want, maybe zero too.

I read Rademacher used de transform $z = e^{2 \pi i \tau}$ using a contour based on Ford circles, but I think I don't need Ford circles here. Anyway I don't know how I should to continue, if I should use the transform previously cited or another, or none.

By the way this is my first question in this marvelous forum, so I apologize if I make mistakes in my English.

Comment: It appears to me that the integral does not exist.

Comment: I think Its posibble tha the value of the integral depends of $\varepsilon$, 
the lower value of $\varepsilon$, the higher the value of the integral. I edited the post, I write "bordering" instead of "without going through the", its an important difference